# Knockout.js indexed based color from array

Tags: knockout.js

Hello and thanks in advance.

I am building a custom component and I want to retrieve properties from a component array.

In the component viewModel:

```js
graph.colors = ["#3366cc", "#dc3912", "#ff9900", "#109618", "#990099", "#0099c6", "#dd4477", "#66aa00", "#b82e2e", "#316395", "#994499", "#22aa99", "#aaaa11", "#6633cc", "#e67300", "#8b0707", "#651067", "#329262", "#5574a6", "#3b3eac"];
```

...and then in the template:

```js
<div class="legend" data-bind="foreach: legend">
    <div class="item">
      <span class="box" data-bind="style: { 'background-color': $parent.colors[$index]}"></span>
      <span data-bind="text: $data"></span> <!-- works -->
      <span data-bind="text: $index"></span>  <!-- works -->
      <span data-bind="text: $component.colors[0]"></span> <!-- works -->
      <span data-bind="text: $component.colors[$index]"></span>  <!-- blank! -->
    </div>
  </div>
```

While the `$index` returns correct and `$component.colors` is well defined, the color is not returning.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `index` is a function, when using it as `text: index` it is automatically unwrapped, it also works like that for observables.
But when using it within an array index selector you should add the `()` so it reads:

`<span data-bind="text: $component.colors[$index()]"></span>`

```js
const colors = ["#3366cc", "#dc3912", "#ff9900", "#109618", "#990099", "#0099c6", "#dd4477", "#66aa00", "#b82e2e", "#316395", "#994499", "#22aa99", "#aaaa11", "#6633cc", "#e67300", "#8b0707", "#651067", "#329262", "#5574a6", "#3b3eac"];

ko.applyBindings();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<ul data-bind="foreach: { data: [...Array(10).keys()], as: 'item' }">
  <li data-bind="text: colors[$index()]"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Correct, I found out the exact moment your answer came. Thank you!